# Ruby on Rails - How to combine display Search results in the View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, view

I have Search controller that searches 2 models - Posts and Categories. The search works, however I am unable to display results in the View correctly - I can't get category names to show up.

I am very confused and frustrated at this point and hope to find some help!
I'm pretty sure (99% sure) the problem is in the View somewhere, because I can get results to display through render inspect thingy.

SearchController.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
    @categories = Category.search(params[:search])

    # combine the results
    @results = @posts + @categories
    @results.uniq   # may be necessary to remove duplicates
  end
end
```

index.html.erb (views/search)

```
<%= render 'posts/posts', :posts => @posts %>
```

_posts.html.erb (view/posts)

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Flag</th>
  </tr>

  <% if posts %>
    <% posts.each do |post| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= post.name %></td>
      <td><%= post.category.name %></td>
      <td><%= post.description %></td>
      <td><%= post.flag %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <tr><td>No posts</td></tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

I can get posts that match the search to display, but I can't display categories. How can I do this? Any help highly appreciated!! Thank you.

Comment: I have solved my problem. I don't quite understand why it works yet. But essentially it's looking for files /categories/_category and /posts/_post that I didn't have. THIS IS NOT OBVIOUS, RUBY! NOT OBVIOUS. I deleted everything in the Controller except the first line. I did not modify _posts.html.erb . I will post complete code in the answer later. I also like kobaltz's solution if using sunspot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a search backend like `sunspot solr` then you would be able to combine the searches like

```
@search = Sunspot.search [User, Company] do
  fulltext params[:search]
end
@results = @search.results
```

And then return the necessary values. In this example, it's showing where you can retrieve the class of the action (controller_name) may not work depending on which controller the results are returned in.

```
        <% @results.each do |result| %>
            <% case result.class.to_s %>
                <% when "Company" %>
                    <li><%= "Company: #{result.name}" %></li>
                <% when "User" %>
                    <li><%= "User: #{result.username}" %></li>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: I am not using any backend search programs. I would really like to solve this without resorting to sunspot or any other search program, but if I can't I will have to try this. Thank you.

Comment: I just tried this on another app and I'm not getting anything out of @search.results , how does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

**The answer** (I include all the things I changed to make it work + few files that I didn't change but that have to be there), **or How to make simple search for multiple models**:

SearchController.rb

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
  end
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id :name :description :flag

  belongs_to :category

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :joins => :category, :conditions => ['posts.equipment LIKE ? OR posts.description LIKE ? or categories.name like ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

search/index.html.erb

```
<%= render 'posts/posts', :posts => @posts %>
```

I added 2 files _post.html.erb and _category.html.erb. They are similar, this is _post.html.erb:

```
post: <%= post.name %>
```

(This might not be necessary in some cases or for some models. I can search a third model without this file in its' views. However the third model doesn't have file like _posts.html.erb either).
Finally, _posts.html.erb remains the same:

```
...
<% if posts %>
  <% posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.name %></td>
    <td><%= post.category.name %></td>
    <td><%= post.description %></td>
    <td><%= post.flag %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <tr><td>No posts</td></tr>
<% end %>
...
```

This works now. Can add new models to the search easily. The only other thing needed for the search is input field.